# setValue not working in some Google app scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have several Google forms that populate a Google sheet.

In most this line works as intended, triggered on form submit :

`sheet.getRange(lastRow, getColIndexByName("Status")).setValue("New");`

In one project it does not, the value is not set, however when viewing the execution transcript there is a line that states:

`[18-06-12 05:58:08:572 PDT] Range.setValue([New]) [0.122 seconds]`

I have checked that the text color was not the same as the background.

I have tried isolating this code in a function by itself.

It worked for a short while after a new sheet was generated for the form.

What am I missing?

Comment: I suggest changing the argument `getColIndexByName("Status")` to a hard coded number, and test it.  Also, remove and re-install your "On Form Submit" trigger.

Comment: Well Sandy, changing to the hard coded col number worked. Not sure why it works in one instance and not the other by name. Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: `getColIndexByName("Status")` is returning something unexpected.  You may need to separate that code out, and test for bad values.

Comment: Now the hard coded line is not working.....execution log says it completed.....

Comment: If the code was working, and now is not working without you having changed anything, then it's unlikely that it's an error in your code.  And if the code is running, it can't be the trigger.  But other than those two things, I don't know what else the problem could be.  You might want to look in your Apps Script dashboard and see if there are any errors.  From the script editor, right click the Apps Script icon in the upper left, and choose "open in another tab."  That opens the Apps Script dashboard.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've set the project to "monitor" in the dashboard, hopefully that will shed some light on the situation.

Comment: Also tried reading the value after setting it at the suggestion of an issue report for this, it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen [here](https://sites.google.com/site/nnillixxsource/Roberts/RoseCMMSv020/global/getColIndexByName_js) function `getColIndexByName(sheet, colName)`. I don't know this documentation is perfect or not, but try once.

> This function has 2 arguments: Sheet & colName. so you missing 1st argument
>   `sheet`.

I see that you want to set value in last row. But keep in mind that function `getColIndexByName` will search word in 1st row.

Comment: The function I am using has only one.

Comment: `function getColIndexByName(colName) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var numColumns = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var row = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, numColumns).getValues();
  for (i in row[0]) {
    var name = row[0][i];
    if (name == colName) {
      return parseInt(i) + 1;
    }
  }`
  return -1;
}